# changing the value of a variable multiple times and keeping that variable value throughout the entire loop in arduino

Tags: arduino

In Arduino I am having issues where I can't change the value of a variable in the `void loop()`. Here is the code I use:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}

int speed = 1000;
int sub = 100;

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(13) == HIGH) {
    speed = speed-sub; 
  } else {
    speed = speed;
  }
  
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(speed);
  
  if (digitalRead(13) == HIGH) {
    speed = speed - sub; 
  } else {
    speed = speed;
  }
  
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(speed);
  
  if (digitalRead(13) == HIGH) {
    speed = speed - sub;
  } else {
    speed = speed;
  }
  
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(speed);
}
```

Is there any way I can change the value of a variable multiple times during one loop and have that variable value kept until the end of the loop? Also, will I need to add a new function, and if so how should I go about it?

Comment: You read from pin 13, but never set it to input. You don't need to do `speed = speed` - just drop the `else` clauses. I don't see any problem otherwise. I would put the output pin states in an array, and use that to update the pins. Just do one test each time through the loop: test, turn off pins, bump index (wrap around if needed), set the new pin value, and delay. Let the power of the forever `loop` do some of the work for you.

Comment: in else use speed=1000; instead speed=speed

Comment: i thought i put it as pin 10?

Comment: im confused at my own code now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to control the speed of a running light using push button.

but in your code that is not possible because you use blocking function that will disable reading of button for a while.

i suggest you run the code in your mind line by line. then you will understood what i mean.

Comment: alright ill see if this helps me sorry for taking so long to respond